# Sunspot Solr: auto_index not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, spree, sunspot

I'm using sunspot for handling solr in my spree commerce application.
I've defined it for my product model:

```
Spree::Product.class_eval do
  searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do
  ...
  end
end
```

At index time, everything gets into Solr and works fine. But when I try to edit a product, the changes aren't saved to Solr. For example, adding a unique word like `testtest` to the title of a product, and then search for that keyword returns nothing. When I reindex the whole database, it works.

Inside the `sunspot.yml` I'm using the `auto_commit_after_request: true` option.

I tailed the `log/sunspot-solr-development.log` where every search gets logged. But it seems that editing a product doesn't make any call to Solr. I thought that using the `:auto_index => true` option would trigger the saves to the database (in production I'm going to use the `autoCommit` feature from Solr).

So, I'm a little bit stuck. I have no idea, where sunspot hooks into the save blocks, or is it RSolr in the background? Maybe someone can help me to fix this problem.

**EDIT**

I just saw, that when using Sunspot, the model class gets some methods like `index` and `index!`. The strange thing is, that inside the console `rails c` this methods are listed when calling `Spree::Product.first.methods`. But when I hook into the update method from the products controller, this methods aren't there. So maybe I have some problems during initializing the sunspot stuff.

FYI: The code from above (`Spree::Product.class_eval do`) is inside an initializer under `config/initializers/sunspot/sunspot_product.rb`.

Comment: which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p392 and Rails 3.2.9

Comment: Nobody an idea? I can't figure out, where to start to debug this problem :(

Comment: @23tux how did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use solr_index and solr_index! methods from the controller.

[solr_index api documentation](http://sunspot.github.io/sunspot/docs/Sunspot/Rails/Searchable/InstanceMethods.html#solr_index-instance_method)

Answer (score 0):

After years has been passed I like to provide the another option for this question.

You can edit the **solrconfig.xml** and set the

**autoSoftCommit**

to any milliseconds that you want to index. You might not want to reinvent the whole wheel by indexing the records by yourself.

Also take a look at this reference
[When should we apply Hard commit and Soft commit in SOLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998804/when-should-we-apply-hard-commit-and-soft-commit-in-solr)